# Javascript breaks on mobile device (iphone 4s), But gets fixed once "request desktop site" is enabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, mobile, knockout.js

I have a site that uses knockout.js and it works perfectly fine on a PC but when i try and open it on my mobile device javascript kinda breaks and the site stops working.

When I open it with google chrome there is an option "Request desktop mode". When i enable that the site loads as if i'm loading it from a PC and everything works fine.

Can you please tell me how to always make the site open as a desktop site on all devices that open it or how to overcome the problem another way.

Addition: When I open it in Safari it is ok. But i tried on my friend's iPad and javascript was kinda broken and not working.

Just an addition:
I am using ASP.NET 
and have the following added to the site:

```
<browsers>
    <browser id="CriOS" parentID="Safari">
      <identification>
        <userAgent match="CriOS" />
      </identification>

      <capabilities>
        <capability name="browser" value="CriOS" />
        <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
        <capability name="javascript" value="true" />
        <capability name="javascriptversion" value="1.8" />
      </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

**Edit:** Css is also kinda different.
**Edit2:** This is the phone's user agent Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOs/27.0.1453.10 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25(936BD788-9191-4BD9-A280-60406A97B56C)

I was able to reproduce the bug in my Pc's chrome. It appends some strange guid to the url

> http://site.com/(F(nM9gQyp4Gyyp1ue_1FJGkIalUQqd_XjPZRrksWTgI_XHSq7AyI1J9h2lQVt-cFWR8kgJFiY0AFgwq580zjch5Gb5D_Kz_yGRlQLjqC_YoLrliY-Pc0CAfrtzUNwYpcg22z-Maqc1z3s9hUPLq_yTM0R1e9yJ1x13674kZhJXGnVmeb8Tmrp9F6hmLNaTTGQK0))

I guess this breaks my site.

Comment: It sounds like the desktop site and what ever is presented to mobile/tablet users contains different javaScript. Can you request the mobile site in a desktop browser (maybe with a user Agent switcher to fake an ipad request) or enable the debug console in mobile Safari to see what is failing? I'm afraid there isn't enough information in this question to likly get a clear answer (could be wrong though, there are some crazy geniuses on this site)

Comment: The sad thing is changing the user agent does not break it. I really could not find how to enable remote debugging or enabling debug console on the phone.

Comment: I managed opening it with this http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php and the javascript breaks saying: Unexpected identifier 
Oops, something is not defined.\nUncaught ReferenceError: Type is not defined

Comment: Some browsers throw exceptions when js objects have extra commas when inline initializing (IE6/7/8 come to mind). Not sure about iOS/Safari, but it could be something similar.

For example, `var someObj = { foo : 123, bar : 456, };` => works in all modern browsers but fails under ie7/8 because of the extra comma after `bar: 456`.

Basically, there has to be some js 'error' that modern PC browsers skip over while iOS/mobile browsers crash.

Comment: I found the solution:  <forms loginUrl="Authentication/Login.aspx" timeout="10000" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
setting cookieless to UseCookies solved the problem

Comment: Can you find out what changed in your page's js? I'm curious about that.

Comment: It is because of the strange guid that represents the session id when cookies are disabled - it gets appended to the url resulting in invalid urls pointing to the *.axd files. Change in javascript was that it was missing.